# Cascading of S-Matrices using T-parameters messes up S11 and S22?

Tags: transmission-line, microwave, microstrip

I wanted understand how cascading works and so I modelled a microstripline of say length 'L' in CST and got its S-params. Then I simulated a line of length 'L/2' and got the results. So, the response of line of length 'L' should be the cascaded responses of two 'L/2' lines right? Anyway, I converted them to T-params and got the resultant S-params. However, only S12 and S21 matches the S-params of line 'L' whereas S11 and S22 vary significantly. I tried with different structures, for example with a mitered bend but in each case S11 and S22 vary significantly. I was wondering if anyone can explain why this is?

Comment: the equations you should use for cascading S matrices are different to T matrices are different to chain (ABCD) matrices. Make sure you're using the correct cascading form for the type of matrix you have. It's only mathematics, it will *just work* if you use the correct equations. Perhaps post the matrices you have, and the equations you used to cascade them.

Comment: @Neil_UK https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/transfer-s-parameters . Those are the equations I used.

Comment: so break it down. Cascade the L/2 S matrices as S parameters, does it work? Convert each L/2 S matrix to T and back again, are they the same? Convert the L/2 and the L S matrices to T matrices, multiply the L/2 T matrices, does the result match the L T matrix? Finally, convert L/2 S to T, multiply, convert back to S. Now, which of those steps are correct, and which show a problem?

Comment: @Neil_UK figured it out, posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Clarifying for anyone with the same question.

When I was comparing the S parameters, I was computing the relative error for the individual elements of the S-matrix. The right way to do it is as follows

$$\frac{\begin{bmatrix}S11c&S12c\\S21c&S22c\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}S11&S12\\S21&S22\end{bmatrix}}{Norm(\begin{bmatrix}S11&S12\\S21&S22\end{bmatrix})}$$

Where the S-parameters succeeded by a 'c' are the result of the cascaded network and the those without are the result of the composite un-cascaded system.

The elements of the resultant matrix will give the correct relative error. The reason why this happens is because, in a perfectly matched microstrip trace S11 and S22 are negligibly small as a result supposing the composite system has S11=-0.0009 and the cascaded system has S11=0.0003 (linear) the error will be around 133% but one can see that these two are almost equivalent. The above method will hence give a more accurate result.

Comment: are you saying you were looking at the differences of rounding errors?????

Comment: @Neil_UK Nope. When trying to find the relative error, I was finding it for each element rather than compute it for the matrix as a whole and then extract the elements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743044/relative-error-between-two-matrices