# How do you chain 2-port S-parameters onto a 1-port S-parameter?

Tags: rf, filter, impedance, impedance-matching, s-parameters

With 2-port S-parameters, you can build up a circuit by chaining them together using [ABCD or T-parameters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/620767/256265), simply multiply the matrices:

[image: ABCD and T parameters]

We have measured a complex single port S-parameter of an antenna.  I would like to chain 2-port S-parameter impedance match matrices (from .s2p's) in front of the 1-port antenna measurement (.s1p) such that the result is a single port matrix of the entire system. Thus, the result is composed of several 2-port matrices (chained) and terminated by the 1-port antenna S-parameters, producing a 1-port matrix. This would allow us to estimate impedance match behavior for the antenna with the match.

Of course there are software packages out there that do this, but I am writing my own [RF library in Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/RF::Component) and would like to add 1-port chaining as a feature.

**Question:**

First we have to transform the 1-port S-parameter matrix to "ABCD compatible" parameters so that they can be multiplied to the 2-port matrices. What is the math for that transform?

Is the resulting single port matrix simply multiplied against the 2-port ABCD- or T-parameter matrix, or does 2-to-1-port composition differ somehow?

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia (or pretty well any rf/microwave text covering S-parameters):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_parameters

[image]